# SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT has no effect when am select?

Tags: android

When I am debugging app is going to crash? I added my code below and am using android 7.1 please check and help me ?

```
    public void setTimeout(int screenOffTimeout) {
        int time;
        switch (screenOffTimeout) {
            case 0:
                time = 30000;
                break;
            case 1:
                time = 60000;
                break;
            case 2:
                time = 300000;
                break;
            case 3:
                time = 600000;
                break;
            case 4:
                time = 1800000;
                break;
            default:
                time = 30000;
        }
        Settings.System.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT,time);
    }
```

Comment: Add your adb logs as well. What error you are getting?

Comment: am not getting any error in log .am not getting any response its idle